# Pandas how to split vlaues of every column based on colon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am trying to split all the column values and want to retain only second index ie `-1`, it works with the individual columns like `str.split(': ').str[-1]` but as being a novice learner I'm not able to apply it for all columns.

Indeed I want to retain the values from every column after `:`.

Maybe writing a function and applying that to df but not getting that.

Dataframe:

```
>>> df
                LoginShell            ExpiryDate                              UID
0    loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991212                    uid: auto_soc
1    loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991212                    uid: sambakul
2    loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991212         uid: services2go-jenkins
3    loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991212                     uid: rdtest0
4    loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991212                        uid: sudo
..                     ...                   ...                              ...
171  loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991230                      uid: elmadm
172  loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991231                         uid: git
173  loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991231                     uid: rhspadm
174  loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991231                     uid: bossadm
175  loginShell: /bin/bash  Enddate: 20991231  uid: ngvp_vmware_management_tst

[176 rows x 3 columns]
```

Result for individual column:

```
>>> df['LoginShell'].str.split(': ').str[-1]
0      /bin/bash
1      /bin/bash
2      /bin/bash
3      /bin/bash
4      /bin/bash
         ...
171    /bin/bash
172    /bin/bash
173    /bin/bash
174    /bin/bash
175    /bin/bash
Name: LoginShell, Length: 176, dtype: object
```

Expected values:

```
              LoginShell            ExpiryDate                              UID
0             /bin/bash             20991212                                auto_soc
1             /bin/bash             20991212                                sambakul
```

Any help will be so helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(': ', 1)[-1])
```

`df`:

```
  LoginShell ExpiryDate                  UID
0  /bin/bash   20991212           au:to:_soc
1  /bin/bash   20991212             sambakul
2  /bin/bash   20991212  services2go-jenkins
3  /bin/bash   20991212              rdtest0
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LoginShell': ['loginShell: /bin/bash', 'loginShell: /bin/bash',
                   'loginShell: /bin/bash', 'loginShell: /bin/bash'],
    'ExpiryDate': ['Enddate: 20991212', 'Enddate: 20991212',
                   'Enddate: 20991212', 'Enddate: 20991212'],
    'UID': ['uid: au:to:_soc', 'uid: sambakul', 'uid: services2go-jenkins',
            'uid: rdtest0']
})

df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(': ', 1)[-1])
```

---

As a `def` function rather than a `lambda`:

```
def split_on_first_colon(x):
    return x.split(': ', 1)[-1]


df = df.applymap(split_on_first_colon)
```

Comment: nice! although if we have any extra " :" in the strings then this will return just the final part. So could be safer to do `df.applymap(lambda x: ': '.join(x.split(': ')[1:]))`

Comment: This looks very nice @Henry Ecker, how we can write function for the same just in case for another way around.

Comment: Updated to be multi-colon safe @Matt. See first row as example.

Comment: @HenryEcker, i mean like `def split_vlaues(): return something` and then apply.  sorry i'm just throwing my idea i may be wrong.  anyways i accepted the answer and already +1.

Comment: Just for learning purpose nothing more than that :-).

Comment: Sure. I've added a `def` function option to the end of my answer @kulfi

Comment: @HenryEcker, Ever grateful of you and thank you for going extra mile to add another answer.